# Regex in scala string

Tags: regex, string, scala

I have a scala string like this:

> HttpResponse({"data":[{"text":"I love Titanic.","polarity":4,"meta":{"language":"en"}}]}
>   ,200,Map(Content-Length -> Vector(76), Content-Type -> Vector(application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1), Date -> Vector(Thu, 28 Apr 2016 16:51:45 GMT), Server -> Vector(Google Frontend), Status -> Vector(HTTP/1.1 200 OK)))

I want to extract the integer after the word polarity which is 4
using regex in scala.

Comment: can't you get that information as an HttpResponse, or a json, instead of that **ugly** string?

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val str = """HttpResponse({"data":[{"text":"I love Titanic.","polarity":4,"meta":{"language":"en"}}]} ,200,Map(Content-Length -> Vector(76), Content-Type -> Vector(application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1), Date -> Vector(Thu, 28 Apr 2016 16:51:45 GMT), Server -> Vector(Google Frontend), Status -> Vector(HTTP/1.1 200 OK)))"""
str: String = HttpResponse({"data":[{"text":"I love Titanic.","polarity":4,"meta":{"language":"en"}}]} ,200,Map(Content-Length -> Vector(76), Content-Type -> Vector(application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1), Date -> Vector(Thu, 28 Apr 2016 16:51:45 GMT), Server -> Vector(Google Frontend), Status -> Vector(HTTP/1.1 200 OK)))

scala> """polarity":(\d+),""".r.findFirstMatchIn(str).map(_.group(1))
res15: Option[String] = Some(4)
```

But you probably rather want to take the json and parse it into a case class.